# How can I get all attributes on a parameter, within an ActionFilter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a controller:

```
public class CatController
{

public something DoStuff([FromBody]string bibble)
{

}

}
```

I want to create an ActionFilter and loop through each parameter, and see what attributes that parameter has, such as [FromBody]. How can I do this?

```
public class InspectParametersActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        actionContext.ActionDescriptor.?
        actionContext.ActionArguments.?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var allCustomAttributes = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters()
        .Select(s => s.GetCustomAttributes(false));
}
```